# OpenVPN is installed but it is not an avaliable option in the network manager

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have installed and used openVPN once before in a previous install of Ubuntu 12.04. I have since reformatted, and now after reinstalling openVPN it will not show up in the network manager. I am trying to setup my VPN connection and the only option I have to choose from is PPTP.

EDIT: I have Gnome Shell and KDE installed as well, Gnome being my primary. I cannot find OpenVPN in either Gnome or Unity, however I can add it without an issue in KDE. Not really an acceptable workaround, but it works for now. I would still like to be able to do it in GTK based desktops as well.

Comment: OH, sorry about that, I really didn’t know. Ill go do that right now.

Answer (score 18):

You need to install the Network Manager OpenVPN plugin for Gnome.

- Open a terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
- `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome`

Now try again.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I already tried. I just now tried it again for good measure. Still a no go. I even did a "complete Removal" of openvpn through synaptic, and reinstalled. But it still wont give me the option.

Comment: I see your KDE/Gnome situation from the edit - please install `network-manager-openvpn-gnome` and see!