# OpenVPN not showing when trying to configure a new VPN

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, openvpn

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I tried to configure a new OpenVPN connection, but when I try to add one only PPTP is shown like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148016/openvpn-is-installed-but-it-is-not-an-avaliable-option-in-the-network-manager). The answer for that question is not working.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

To get the VPN connection to show up in Network Manager, ensure that all these packages are installed:

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

(From [Ubuntu 16.04 OpenVPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn/760679#760679)) - this should be closed as a duplicate but can't be yet because of the bounty.

Comment: For `openvpn` only `network-manager-openvpn` and
`network-manager-openvpn-gnome` are needed (is my current config). _vpnc (cisco)_ and _pptp (Microsoft's point to point tunneling)_ are different _VPN protocols_.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the OpenVPN package for NetworkManager to be aware of OpenVPN and connections using this.

Fortunately, this is just a one-liner:

```
sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn
```

This will install NetworkManager awareness, and all required dependencies (if any) to set up and maintain connections. After install, however, you may need to reboot (or at least log out/back in) for the Network Manager to figure out it has new capabilities.

Depending on your system, you may also need to install the `network-manager-vpnc` package.