# Configure VPN option missing on menu.

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148016/openvpn-is-installed-but-it-is-not-an-avaliable-option-in-the-network-manager) example, and also read the ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html) to set up a VPN.

My issue is that:

> set up the VPN connection:
>   Click the network menu on the menu bar and, under VPN Connections, select Configure VPN.

is not possible, since I do not have the Cinfigure VPN, see pic.

[image]

Not sure what I have to enable/configure to have this option.
Thanks

Comment: If it worked before, I found out that simple `se̶r̶v̶i̶c̶e̶ ̶n̶e̶t̶w̶o̶r̶k̶-̶m̶a̶n̶a̶g̶e̶r̶ ̶r̶e̶s̶t̶a̶r̶t̶` isn't enough I literally had to do `service network-manager stop` wait for it to stop and then `service network-manager start`, and then it started working again, if never worked before, make sure the appropriate packages are installed as in the answers below :)

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, however I found a work around on ubuntu 16.4.

Make sure you have installed all the steps in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn/760679#760679);

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

Then pick the 'edit connections' option at the bottom of the menu you show. In the window that pop up hit 'Add'. In the window that this creates you will see a drop down menu. Scroll far enough and you will see your vpn options; 
[image: Add connection dialogue, with vpn option selected.]

Hit create and you will be offered all the usual settings.